# I created a matlab function which inputs are the mathematical expression and their parameters. How can I create a GUI for my function?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I defined a mathematical function in this way

```
formula = @(a,b) a+b ;
```

i used "formula" as an argument to a matlab function:

```
function  result = myfunction(formula,a,b)

          result = formula(a,b);

end
```

and everything works fine

```
formula = @(a,b) a+b ;
result=myfunction(formula,3,2)

result =

     5
```

but my aim is to create a GUI, and so i tried the following:

```
    % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
    function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    formula=get(handles.edit1,'String');
    a=str2double(get(handles.edit2,'String'))
    b=str2double(get(handles.edit3,'String'))

    result = formula(a,b);

    set(handles.text1,'string',result);
```

but i get this error:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in untitled>pushbutton1_Callback (line 86)
result = formula(a,b);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in untitled (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `get(handles.edit1,'String')` is not a function, its a `char` array. You should convert it to a function:

```
formula=str2func(['@(a,b)' get(handles.edit1,'String')])
```

Comment: thank you very much, you solved my problem. there is only a small correction to do: get(handles.edit1,'String')]) returns a cell , so before str2func()  we put :     formula=formula{1};     and then:  formula=str2func(formula);